# Is grouping View Model properties into different categories a good practice?

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm, software-design

I'm working on a WPF project using the MVVM pattern and I was wondering if I can improve the internal structure of my ViewModel by abstracting its exposed properties into separate classes.

It's common practice for VMs to contain lots of properties laying around in the same class: Some are used to retrieved user inputs, some are used to expose commands, others to expose the models, and probably some other properties for the view model's own business logic. Not to mention that these properties often have set and get bodies that adds some bulk to the package. This can quickly become messy inside a VM class and finding one's way there can become challenging.

As a way to solve this issue, I am exploring with my team the idea of grouping properties inside my VM into different categories. As a first approach, I chose to group them this way:

**ViewData**, **UserInputs** and  **Commands**, each one represented by its own class. Then I referenced them as properties inside my VM class.

My intention is that these classes will only act as placeholders to free up the bloat in my VM and keep it clean and focused only on interaction logic for handling user events.

It's a simple refactoring, but I get the following pros:

- Cleaner and readable VM.
- Easier binding from the XAML because you know what the entry point is/should be.

Let me elaborate on the latter one: If I want to bind a text box to a property of my VM, I know the binding expression should start with `Userinput.MyVMProperty`. If I need to show a value from my VM, I know my binding's entry point is going to be `ViewData.MyOtherVMProperty`. Binding intellisense will also become better because when you know your entry point, the
suggestion list would be smaller and more focused. This also works the other way around: when reading through your XAML controls, any binding that starts with UserInput necessarily means it's a a control that should send data back to the VM.

The only cons I can find is that this will require creating extra classes for each VM, but I believe it's a fair price to pay for the benefits you get.

Take note that the grouping I suggested may not be the best, but I don't mind any other grouping as long as it solves the problem with bulky VMs.

So, has any one ever tried a similar pattern? Do you think this is a good idea/practice? What other good practices I can use to improve my VMs?

Bonus question: One developer in my team who seemed to agree with this idea, suggested to go the extra mile and consider the grouped classes as VM dependencies and that they need to be injected inside the VM. What do you think about this?

Comment: Interesting, one question thou - how are you going to treat properties which are both - `UserInput` and `ViewData` ? Let's say there is a textbox that should show user's name - it can be edited as well as viewed, and your view in both cases shows user name in textbox. So in this case `UserName` can be treated both - as `UserInput` bcuz it can be changed and `ViewData` bcuz you use this property to show user name on the form. So how are you going to handle those kind of scenarios?

Comment: @Michael: One rule I can establish is that ViewData should only contain properties that are for display only. Anything else that goes from view to VM can be considered as UserInput even if it's also used for display. I'm open to other kinds of grouping like grouping UserInputs and ViewData in the same group for instance.

Answer (score 0):

So for every `ViewModel` you need to create own inner classes for every group. You cannot use `Interfaces` because `ViewModel`s have different properties and commands

Then did you considered that every "groupclass" must to "know" about other groups for `ViewModel` will work properly. 
In my opinion `Class` should be solid logical structure with minimal outside dependency.

Based on the pros you trying to achieve I can suggest another approach without changing structure of the ViewModel classes

Readability can be achieved partly by `#regions`.
Or use `Partial class` for separating different groups in the different files,
while keeping them inside one logical structure
`Intellisense` can be improved by naming conveniences - using prefix based on group property belong to. For example `UserInputMyName`, `ViewDataFullName` or `CommandDelete`

Comment: If a group needs to know about another group, the knowledge can defined inside the VM since it has access to all the groups. Partial classes seems like a good idea to explore, I rarely use them except for for view codebehind classes.

Comment: I affraid putting groups in the own classes make ViewModel too complicated for maintaining